# MS Teams Bot message-extension- Agent returned unsuccessful status code InternalServerError

Tags: javascript, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I have a problem with the configuration of the bot in message-extension. I am using the app in MS Teams for both the bot (message-extension in channels only) and tabs for personal use. Everything locally worked. As I published for the organization, only tabs works, message-extension does not respond to the query and to the others, that is, the whole for the bot solution does not work.

Result: Unable to reach app. Please try again.

After checking in the console, I see something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4f1R.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66MK3.png)

Locally for the bot, I use the Bot Framework implemented by dev.teams.microsoft, while the production version of the bot is generated for Azure as Azure Bot.

This is the configuration I have for env local files:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgaDh.png)

For the production version, on the other hand, I have these:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJYpW.png)

In addition, the Bot was converted to ES6 language, I defined it in package.json to read the type as a module:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKkbc.png)

The manifest.json is set up like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCKbJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vGuS.png)

I'm missing an idea of what to set in Azure or what to set in code to make message-extension start responding to user requests.

Comment: any news? any advice?

Comment: Based on the error message, it seems that there is an issue with the configuration of your bot in the message extension. Could you please check the configuration of your bot in the Teams app manifest? Make sure that the composeExtensions section is correctly defined and that the botId matches the ID of your bot registration. Please verify the app settings as well. Ref code sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/msgext-search/csharp

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT this is a joke of some kind ? this example what you provided is about ngrok and we are struggling to migrate to Azure from a bot imported from https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/ . Unfortunately, but your documentation is very poor, it's like saying about something that something exists but guess how to do it.... It is so annoying -.-.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, I followed this tutorial https://microsoft.github.io/app-camp/new-adventure/05-add-sso/, all works fine in local, but I get "Agent returned unsuccessful status code InternalServerError" when I publish the bot on Azure...

I'll return here if I find something

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: @David Dupré, ok so if you find it, let me know how solve it..

Comment: The problem has been solved on my side.
My application crashed because I forgot to set the parameters for the properties used locally, which I hadn't entered in the .env file for my Azure environment...

To investigate what's going on, I invite you to consult your application logs using the App Service Editor tool and by looking at the output traces.

Thank you.

Comment: @DavidDupré where ? i not see here...

Comment: On your azure web app ressource, in the left blade ther is "Development Tools" section where you should see the "App Service Editor" tool.